# ReferenceError: recordSet is not defined

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2012

`

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

//database congigurSEation

var config = {
  user: "USERNAME",
  password: "SIFRE",
  database: "UpShift",
  server: "DESKTOP-EH2NO0D\\SQLEXPRESS",
  driver: "msnodesqlv8",
  optiions: {
    trustedConnettion: true,
  },
};

// connet to database

sql.connect(config, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  //create teh request object

  var request = new sql.Request();

  //database query

  request.query("select * from ulogin", function (err, recordSet) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }else {
      console.log(recordSet);
    }

  });

});
```

`

ReferenceError: recordSet is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\dmin_dashbaord_v23_html_css_js_bootstap5-main\index.js:38:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
const result = request.query("select * from ulogin");
console.log("Result: ",result.recordsets); // or 'recordset' for first array
```